# Use CSSTransitionGroup to encounter problems

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I used the CSSTransitionGroup to do the simulation of the reactor, but there is no effect, there is no error, the key is set up, css import success, but no effect.

```
  render() {
    var kk = new Date().getTime();
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <div className="leftNav" style={styles.leftNav}>
            {leftNav()}
          </div>
          <div className="content" style={styles.content}>
            <CSSTransitionGroup
              transitionName="a"
              transitionAppear={true}
              transitionAppearTimeout={500}
              transitionEnterTimeout={500}
              transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
              <div key={location.pathname}>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Com1}/>
                <Route exact path="/com1" component={Com1}/>
                <Route exact path="/com2" component={Com2}/>
                <Route exact path="/todo" component={TodoList}/>
                <Route exact path="/com3" component={Com3}/>
              </div>
            </CSSTransitionGroup>
          </div>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
```

Please give me some hints。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Animated Add-Ons](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#high-level-api-reactcsstransitiongroup) documentation.

> **Note**:
>   You must provide the ***key attribute for all children*** of ReactCSSTransitionGroup, even when only rendering a single item. This is how React will determine which children have entered, left, or stayed.

In your example you have one child of your `< CSSTransitionGroup />` component. It never changes, *leaves or enters the DOM*... but it's children do.

Remove the `<div />` and wrap your route handlers with your `< CSSTransitionGroup />`. Make sure to provide each `<Route />` a unique key!

Here is a working example project [react-router-transition](https://github.com/maisano/react-router-transition).

Here is a [github issue](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/issues/37#issuecomment-300837779) where a solution is found.

Here is a paste of the referenced solution, credit @resting

```
<Router>
  ...
  <nav>
    <NavLink to="/" exact activeClassName="active"> <span>Production</span> </NavLink>
    <NavLink to="/personal" activeClassName="active"> <span>Personal</span> </NavLink>
  </nav>
  ...
  <Route render={({ location }) => (
    <CSSTransitionGroup
      transitionName="slide-left"
      transitionEnterTimeout={300}
      transitionLeaveTimeout={500}
    >
      <Switch key={location.key} location={location}>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Production}/>
        <Route path="/personal" component={Personal}/>
      </Switch>
    </CSSTransitionGroup>
  )}
  />
</Router>
```

Comment: According to your method tried, but still does not work。